# Are there numerical methods that preserve stationary solutions of SDEs?

Tags: stochastic-processes, numerical-methods, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider the stochastic differential equation

$$ \textrm{(Ito)}\quad dX_t=f(X_t)dt + g(X_t)dw $$

whose probability distribution is described by the partial differential equation

$$ p_t = -(fp)_x+\left(\frac{g^2}{2}p\right)_{xx} $$

Are there any numerical solution techniques for the SDE that are guaranteed to preserve stationary distributions for finite time step lengths?

For instance, if $f = g g'$, then $ p(x, t) = 1 $ is a stationary solution. However, if I use the regular Euler-Maruyama method on a nonlinear $g$, I get artificial clustering around regions where $g''$ is large.

Comment: $p(x,t)=1$ is not a probability measure on the real line?

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified: I'm only interested in bounded domains with reflective boundary conditions (and possibly periodic).

Comment: Well, but then typically your SDE will need to involve some local times.

Comment: I don't understand... consider for instance $g=\sin(x)$, $f=\sin(x)\cos(x)$ on the domain $[0, 2\pi]$ with initial distribution $p(x,0)=1/(2\pi)$. Then $p(x,t)=p(x,0)$ solves the equation, right?

Comment: But the SDE may have nothing to do with your $p$ then.